# Invalid URL error displayed when using npm within the VS Code PowerShell command line interface

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, command-line-interface, npm-install

When I try to install a package on my project in the VS Code terminal, like `npm i`, or `npm i express` it always displays the error:

```
The URL http://username:password@ip:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error.
```

I have no idea about these errors:

[image: error_screenshot1]

[image: error_screenshot2]

[image: error_screenshot3]

I tried to change the environment by connecting through a VPN in my Windows 11, then deleting the file
`npmrcby`, before trying `npm cache clean --force`. I also tried `npm install express -g`, and `npm install express --save`, but still failed with the same message.

Comment: have you tried with `--trace-deprecation` as suggested to see the source of the error - also, this doesn't seem to be anything to do with express as such, since `npm -i` results in the same error

Comment: Yep, I try the " node --trace-deprecation " then it display the node version.  followed by the prompt below: 
Type ".help" for more information.
> .help
.break    Sometimes you get stuck, this gets you out
.clear    Alias for .break
.editor   Enter editor mode
.exit     Exit the REPL
.help     Print this help message
.load     Load JS from a file into the REPL session
.save     Save all evaluated commands in this REPL session to a file

Comment: you should include `--trace-deprecation` along with the rest of the arguments, not as the only argument